# Passing $expand parameter to an OData function

Tags: odata, sapui5

So I have implemented a function import using NW Gateway and I was pleasantly surprised to find that I could add the oData query option $expand and it worked!

Now I want to take advantage of that by passing a $expand parameter from my SAPUI5 application. But I can't find a way to make this work. My call looks something like this...

```
oModel.callFunction("/VehicleSearch", {
  method: 'GET',
  urlParameters: {"$expand": "Owner", "SearchString": searchString},
  success: function(oData, response) { },
  failure: $.proxy(function(oError) { } 
});
```

The SearchString parameter is passed but not the $expand.

Comment: $expand seems to work fine with lots of oData services - and while the documentation does not explicitly mention it is does not exclude it either. Here is a working example http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/GetProductsByRating?rating=4&$expand=Supplier

Comment: You are right, UI5 version 1.38 adds $expand for oModel.callFunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI5 version 1.38 will add $expand for oModel.callFunction

Comment: Is there a working example? For me it seems not working (with newer version than 1.38.)

Answer (score 1):

I do not use OData in my current project, thus my knowledge migth not be up to date. As far as I know the $expand parameter does not work for function calls. If you check the implementation of the **callFunction** you'll see why only the search parameter reaches the backend: parameters not defined at the function won't be passed.

Comment: You are right, UI5 version 1.38 adds $expand for oModel.callFunction

Answer (score 1):

You ran into a "currently" missing feature.
UI5 version 1.38 adds **$expand** for oModel.callFunction.

A workaround is to use **read** instead of **callFunction** (add $expand to the url).

```
updateData: function() {
    var oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("idVizFrame");
    var url = "QueryLogAnalysis?viewVariant=myFavorites&$expand=Values&$format=json";
    var parameters = {
        success: function(oData, response) {
            var resultData = JSON.parse(response.body);
            var dataModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(resultData.d.results[0]);
            oVizFrame.setModel(dataModel,"expandWorkaround");
        },
        error: function(oError) {
            console.log(oError);    // i.e.
        }
    };
    var serviceUrl = this.getView().getModel().sServiceUrl;
    var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(serviceUrl);
    oJsonModel.read( url, parameters );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not expand a function Import. Expand is used when entities have associations and you are querying an entity which is associated with one or more of another type. The dependent entities are not automatically fetched unless you put them in the expand list. Function imports are more like function calls. In fact they're limited in what you can return.

Comment: You are right, UI5 version 1.38 will add $expand for oModel.callFunction

Comment: Function Imports define an Entity or EntitySet to be returned. You can expand its associations, just like you expand the Entity or EntitySet itself from read operations.